# Host for website that use node.js

Tags: node.js, hosting, web-hosting

I need a good web hosting where I can use node.js.
I have alot experience about cpanel and basic webhotel but I dont know how to use/install node.js.

I'm mainly using html, php, javascript and mysql but I have some features that need node.js.

Can you help me if you know good sites or you know how to use node.js in cpanel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is good post: http://codecondo.com/hosting-platforms-for-node-js/

These web sites have (pre)installed note.js, so no need aby installation.

Comment: Do you have more information about amazon? Do i need ssh? How it works?

Comment: I recommend another hosting (like appfog or azure), because if you are not professional, you can have problems to run your website or application on it. But if you need more tools like database, virtual clouds, SSH and more... amazon is good place for you.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I got my amazon running with ssh connection